# DropDown Menu Changing OnChange

Tags: html

I have 3 dropdown menu. and all 3 are interlinked. ie, if i select the values of 1st dropdown, depending on that the second dropdown should display values. depending on the selection of 2nd dropdown, 3rd dropdown should populate the values. have done for 1st and 2nd. but depending on the values of 2nd drop down am not able to populate the values of 3rd dropdown. can anyone plaz help me. i know something like this will be in JFIDDLE.com. but not able to fine the exact name to search that!

Comment: Have used a java Script like this for the 1st 2 drop down..



 function setBrand(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.Brand1;
var selbox1 = document.myform.site1;
 
selbox.options.length = 0;
selbox1 .options.length = 0;

if (chosen == " ") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Select',' ');
  
  selbox1.options[selbox1.options.length] = new Option('Select',' ');
 
}
}

Comment: similar you can achieve for third see the demo in link  provided in my answer

Comment: Hi Hemanth, i need it in javaScript. Not in C# :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AJAX if you want that. it will be easy.

```
<select name="ID"
                    id="ID"
                    onchange="DoYourTaskHere(this);">
                        <option value="select" selected="selected">Select</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${A.List}" var="Variable">
                            <option value="${ID}">
                                <c:out value="${ID}" />
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                </select>
```

And in the script you write the code as follows.

```
function loadValue(ID) {
    if (ID.value != "select") {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera,
                                    // Safari
            ValueXmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            ValueXmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        ValueXmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = processLoadValues;
        ValueXmlHttpReq.open("POST", "getValue.htm?ID="
                + ID.value, true);
        ValueXmlHttpReq.send();
    } else {
        var objSelect = document.getElementById("ValueId");
        var currentValueListLength = objSelect.options.length;
        while (currentValueListLength > 0) {
            objSelect.remove(1);
            currentValueListLength--;
        }

        var objSelect = document.getElementById("2ndDropDownWhereYouWantToPopulate");
        var currentSecondValueListLength = objSelect.options.length;
        while (currentSecondValueListLength > 0) {
            objSelect.remove(1);
            currentSecondValueListLength--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allright , here something to get you started :

```
<form name='cars'>
<select name='brand'></select>
<select name='model'></select>
</form>
​
```

and the javascript (i'm using jQuery ) :

```
var application_model = [
    {
    name: "General motors",
    models: [
        "model1", "model2", "model3"
        ]},
{
    name: "Mercedes",
    models: [
        "model4", "model5", "model6"
        ]},
{
    name: "Fiat",
    models: [
        "model7", "model8", "model9"
        ]}
];

var selectedBrandIndex = 0
var selectedModelIndex = 0

function render() {
    // render the first combo
    $('select[name=brand]').empty();
    $.each(application_model, function(index, object) {
        var selected = "";
        if (index == selectedBrandIndex) {
            selected = "selected";
        }
        console.log(this);
        $('select[name=brand]').append("<option value='" + index + "'   " + selected + ">" + object.name + "</option>");
    })

    // render the second combo
    $('select[name=model]').empty();
    $.each(application_model[selectedBrandIndex].models, function(index, object) {
        var selected = "";
        if (index == selectedModelIndex) {
            selected = "selected";
        }
        console.log(this);
        $('select[name=model]').append("<option value='" + index + "'   " + selected + ">" + object + "</option>");
    });
}

function main() {
    $("select[name=brand]").bind("change", function(event) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
        selectedBrandIndex = event.currentTarget.value;
        render();
    });
    render();
}

main();​
```

check the fiddle here :

http://jsfiddle.net/camus/MAgza/2/

cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can try related combobox

You can easily setup any number of combobox instances on a single page. They can interact with each other based on certain client or server side events.

This example shows how the comboboxes can interact with each other using client-side methods and requesting the items on demand. To request the items on demand at the client-side, the requestItems() method is used.

The ViewState of the dependent comboboxes is disabled because the data required for their proper operation in this example is maintained in their ClientState.

refer http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Hey this is exactly what am looking for. but where are the values of list1, list2, list3 stored?

Comment: values are filled from arr categories["startList"] = ["Wearing Apparel","Books"]
categories["Wearing Apparel"] = ["Men","Women","Children"];
categories["Books"] = ["Biography","Fiction","Nonfiction"];
categories["Men"] = ["Shirts","Ties","Belts","Hats"];
categories["Women"] = ["Blouses","Skirts","Scarves", "Hats"];
categories["Children"] = ["Shorts", "Socks", "Coats", "Nightwear"];
categories["Biography"] = ["Contemporay","Historical","Other"];
categories["Fiction"] = ["Science Fiction","Romance", "Thrillers", "Crime"];categories["Nonfiction"] = ["How-To","Travel","Cookbooks", "Old Churches"];

Comment: Thanks Hemanth. got the 3 dropdowns working. But Have a small problem. Now that my 1st dropdown is linked to 2 other dropdowns. ie if i change the 1st dropdown then i need 2nd and 4th dropdown to change the values accordingly. i should change anything in this ex to achieve this??