# Make 1 dropdown, change 2 other dropdown values

Tags: html

How to make a dropDown linked to 2 dropdown. ie if i select a value of a dropdown then depending on that value 2 more dropdown values should be changes. am using the following example: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/triplecombo.shtml. i need the values of dropdown 2 and dropdown 4 to be populated depending on the values selected on dropdown 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use Ajax if you need to make things without refreshing the page. Here is an answer to your question. hope its suitable. If you know ajax then you can always use this.

[DropDown Menu Changing OnChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990240/dropdown-menu-changing-onchange/11630750#11630750)

Answer (score 0):

What did you try yet? Where are you stuck?

---

Use javascript, just like in your link...

Other examples:

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

http://r-ednalan.blogspot.com/2011/03/dynamic-select-box-using-jquery-ajax.html

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/using-jquery-ajax-populate-selection-list/

http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/

...

Comment: have used to link 1st 3 dropdowns. depending on 1st, 2nd dropdown should populate values. depending on 2nd 3rd should populate. but now i need to populate even 4th dropdown depending on the values of 1st dropdown. am not able to achieve this!